# Correct way of NSString manipulation (memory management) when passing to methods and using returned Nsstring object

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring

I have singleton class, having a reusable code for string manipulation, which some times leaks memory.

```
-(NSString *)getLocalizedString:(NSString *)key
{
@autoreleasepool
{
    FMDatabase *db=[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
    [db open];
//        NSString *uppercaseValue=[key uppercaseString];
    NSString *uppercaseValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[key uppercaseString]];
    NSString *slashRemoved=[uppercaseValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@" "];
    NSString *spaceRemoved=[slashRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    NSString *dotRemoved=[spaceRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    NSString *collanRemoved=[dotRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    NSString *excalmaRemoved=[collanRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@""];
    NSString *commaRemoved=[excalmaRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    NSString *webaddressRemoved=[commaRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ABCCOM" withString:@"ABC.COM"];
    NSString *value=[db stringForQuery:@"select value from language where name=? AND key=?",[Utils getCurrentLanguage],webaddressRemoved];
    if(value==nil)
    {
        value=key;
    }
    return value;

}
```

}

Usage:

```
NSString *textString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[langmodule getLocalizedString:[[arrSetting objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]]];
   [cell.textLabel setText:textString];

[tip setTitle:[langmodule getLocalizedString:[[self.transactionSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"tip"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

***The method getLocalizedString some times leak at
    NSString *value=[db stringForQuery:@"select value from language where name=? AND key=?",[Utils getCurrentLanguage],webaddressRemoved];***

my `+getCurrentLanguage` method looks like this:

```
+(NSString *)getCurrentLanguage
 {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"fr"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"french";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"de"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"german";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"ja"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"japanese";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"es"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"spanish";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"nl"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"dutch";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"pt"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"portuguese";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"chinese";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"ko"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"korean";
}
else if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"it"])
{
    currentLanguage=@"italian";
}
else {
    currentLanguage=@"english";
}

return currentLanguage;
```

}

Is my `getLocaliztionString` fine, or it is having memory issues. The project is on ARC.
thanks & regards

Comment: maybe its the FMDatabase that has a leak? have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

for manage localization in iphone the best way I have found that using TSLanguageManager library you can check this from below link: https://github.com/tonisalae/TSLanguageManager

Comment: thanks for your interest.I am looking for solution not option, we can not as there are lot of dependencies in current project, will look intto it and use in new projects.